# Misunderstanding websocket communication for blockchain when requesting whole chain from a node

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, websocket, blockchain

This is a long post, so I appreciate those who answer it. I am trying to understand the websocket communication in the blockchain example below.

Here is the source code for a node in a blockchain:

```
const BrewChain = require('./brewChain');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const BrewNode = function(port){
    let brewSockets = [];
    let brewServer;
    let _port = port
    let chain = new BrewChain();

    const REQUEST_CHAIN = "REQUEST_CHAIN";
    const REQUEST_BLOCK = "REQUEST_BLOCK";
    const BLOCK = "BLOCK";
    const CHAIN = "CHAIN";

    function init(){

        chain.init();

        brewServer = new WebSocket.Server({ port: _port });

        brewServer.on('connection', (connection) => {
            console.log('connection in');
            initConnection(connection);
        });     
    }

    const messageHandler = (connection) =>{
        connection.on('message', (data) => {
            const msg = JSON.parse(data);
            switch(msg.event){
                case REQUEST_CHAIN:
                    connection.send(JSON.stringify({ event: CHAIN, message: chain.getChain()}))    
                    break;                  
                case REQUEST_BLOCK:
                    requestLatestBlock(connection);
                    break;      
                case BLOCK:
                    processedRecievedBlock(msg.message);
                    break;  
                case CHAIN:
                    processedRecievedChain(msg.message);
                    break;  

                default:  
                    console.log('Unknown message ');
            }
        });
    }


    const processedRecievedChain = (blocks) => {
        let newChain = blocks.sort((block1, block2) => (block1.index - block2.index))

        if(newChain.length > chain.getTotalBlocks() && chain.checkNewChainIsValid(newChain)){
            chain.replaceChain(newChain);
            console.log('chain replaced');
        }
    }

    const processedRecievedBlock = (block) => {

        let currentTopBlock = chain.getLatestBlock();

        // Is the same or older?
        if(block.index <= currentTopBlock.index){
            console.log('No update needed');
            return;
        }

        //Is claiming to be the next in the chain
        if(block.previousHash == currentTopBlock.hash){
            //Attempt the top block to our chain
            chain.addToChain(block);

            console.log('New block added');
            console.log(chain.getLatestBlock());
        }else{
            // It is ahead.. we are therefore a few behind, request the whole chain
            console.log('requesting chain');
            broadcastMessage(REQUEST_CHAIN,"");
        }
    }

    const requestLatestBlock = (connection) => {
        connection.send(JSON.stringify({ event: BLOCK, message: chain.getLatestBlock()}))   
    }

    const broadcastMessage = (event, message) => {
        brewSockets.forEach(node => node.send(JSON.stringify({ event, message})))
    }

    const closeConnection = (connection) => {
        console.log('closing connection');
        brewSockets.splice(brewSockets.indexOf(connection),1);
    }

    const initConnection = (connection) => {
        console.log('init connection');

        messageHandler(connection);

        requestLatestBlock(connection);

        brewSockets.push(connection);

        connection.on('error', () => closeConnection(connection));
        connection.on('close', () => closeConnection(connection));
    }

    const createBlock = (teammember) => {
        let newBlock = chain.createBlock(teammember)
        chain.addToChain(newBlock);

        broadcastMessage(BLOCK, newBlock);

    }

    const getStats = () => {
        return {
            blocks: chain.getTotalBlocks()
        }
    }

    const addPeer = (host, port) => {
        let connection = new WebSocket(`ws://${host}:${port}`);

        connection.on('error', (error) =>{
            console.log(error);
        });

        connection.on('open', (msg) =>{
            initConnection(connection);
        });
    }

    return {
        init,
        broadcastMessage,
        addPeer,
        createBlock,
        getStats
    }

}

module.exports = BrewNode;
```

When a new block is created by the node with the createBlock() function, a message is broadcast from the node to all connected sockets with the broadcastMessage() function to tell them a new block has been created. The connected sockets will receive the message, and in messageHandler() it will hit the BLOCK option in the switch statement for each of them. I have a grasp of this process, and have drawn up a graph to show my understanding.

FIGURE 1

[image]

As stated earlier, when A creates a new block it will send the new block to it's connected nodes, where each node will verify it and possibly add it to it's chain. This processing is done by the processedRecievedBlock() function. Let's say B and C decide to add the block to their chain, but D is several blocks behind so it must request the whole chain from A. **This is where I am confused**. I expected that D would send a message back to A requesting the whole chain, like this:

FIGURE 2

[image]

However, according to the processReceivedBlock() function, in this situation D will broadcast a REQUEST_CHAIN message to all it's connected sockets, when this line is run:

```
broadcastMessage(REQUEST_CHAIN,"");
```

Let's say D is connected to E and F. Instead of requesting the chain from A like in FIGURE 2, it seems as though it will send the REQUEST_CHAIN message to it's connected sockets, like this:

FIGURE 3

[image]

In the messageHandler() function, the REQUEST_CHAIN option in the switch statement will be run for E and F, and they will hit this line of code:

```
connection.send(JSON.stringify({ event: CHAIN, message: chain.getChain()}));
```

It is my understanding that this will cause E and F to send their own chain back to themselves, like this:

FIGURE 4

[image]

I want to know why FIGURE 2 does not occur when D needs to request the whole chain from A. Tracing the code has had me believe that FIGURE 3 and FIGURE 4 occur instead, neither of which seem to be useful.

I am trying to find an understanding of what exactly happens in this code when a node must request the whole chain from another node. I must be misunderstanding what these sockets are doing.

Complete source code: https://github.com/dbjsdev/BrewChain/blob/master/brewNode.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for a descriptive question. :)

You are right for the most part and Figure 3 is the correct description of that part of the process. But Figure 4 is wrong.

Note that every socket connection between peers leads to a different instance of `connection` which are collectively maintained in `brewSockets`.

So, when A/E/F receive a request on `connection` from D, they respond with the whole chain, as in the code below:

```
connection.send(JSON.stringify({ event: CHAIN, message: chain.getChain()}));
```

D then processes the `CHAIN` message:

```
const processedRecievedChain = (blocks) => {
        let newChain = blocks.sort((block1, block2) => (block1.index - block2.index))

        if(newChain.length > chain.getTotalBlocks() && chain.checkNewChainIsValid(newChain)){
            chain.replaceChain(newChain);
            console.log('chain replaced');
        }
}
```

Now, onto the '*why*'!

*Firstly*, the underlying principle is that we trust in the network, not just one node. So, you want to verify the authenticity of the chain from as many sources as possible.

*Secondly*, you want the latest chain from your peers not just any random chain.

By doing so, we ensured that any node is as latest as its peers. So, D node fetched chain from multiple sources and stored the latest verified chain.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Cheers mate.